# Python async function is never awaited

Tags: python, async-await, coroutine, fastapi

I implemented a async function in python's asynchronous framework *FastAPI*

The function looks like:

```
async def func2(num):
  time.sleep(3)
  return num

async def func1():
  text = await func2(5)
  print(text)
  print('inside func1')

async def my_async_func():
  print('start')
  await func1()
  print('finish')
```

Here, when I execute `my_async_func` I'm expecting asyn behavior and values to be printed as

```
start
finish
inside func1
5
```

But it prints synchronously as

```
start
5
inside func1
finish
```

How to handle concurrent operation and implementation of coroutines asynchronously?

Comment: That's the whole point of `await` -- it makes it wait synchronously for the function to return.

Comment: Your code in `func1()`: `print(text)` then `print('inside func1')`, how could you achieve print `5` after `inside func1`? `print` is not async.

Comment: I thought as it is awaited for 3 seconds, `inside func1` will be printed. But actually I expect immediate execution of printing **finish** just before the delay process of `func1` function. How to get ? @jizhihaoSAMA  @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do `asyncio.create_task`, (note: you can't make sure print `5` after `inside func1` by the order of print.)

Try code below:

```
import asyncio
import time


async def func2(num):
    time.sleep(3)
    return num


async def func1():
    text = await func2(5)
    print(text)
    print('inside func1')


async def my_async_func():
    print('start')
    asyncio.create_task(func1())
    print('finish')


asyncio.run(my_async_func())
```

Result:

```
start
finish
5
inside func1
```

---

Also notice that sleep would make **your thread** sleep.

Comment: I would use this.. But you know the _FastAPI_ funct is already an async framework. Don't I have built-in feature without using external library _asyncio_?

Comment: @RishadTanjim Because FastAPI is already an async framework, so you could use it with asyncio(asyncio is a standard module of python).

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous behavior shows up when several independent(ish) tasks take turns executing in an event loop, but here you only run the 1 task `my_async_func`. `my_async_func` then calls `func1`, which then calls `func2`; your program is executing in exactly the order you wrote.

This chain of function calls shouldn't really be called synchronous because there is only 1 independent task. You can see asynchronous behavior if you queue up 2 `my_async_func` tasks, actually.

Comment: Yes but how can I leverage this and what is the solution would be if I could expect it immediately be printed **finish** before concurrent operation ?

Comment: The only way to do that would be to move the `print('finish')` before the `func1` call. `await func1()` means "pause this coroutine until after the function or coroutine `func1` returns.